# Facebook Authentication Problem?

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook integration with Android,
I register an app on Facebook developer side.Before it everything is working fine on both device and emulator.
But when I used same ap after 10-15 days it's not working on device, working fine on emulator.

Please let me know if i am missing anything regarding FB authentication.

Comment: Check if your accessToken is still valid and is not expired.

Comment: I try to use appid using this web url : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/#!/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=105575209538399 . it showing me this error

"An error occurred with MyFrind. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration."

Comment: @Sat : how can I check validation for my app token?

Comment: This might help you in checking,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845151/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-facebook-access-token-is-still-valid