# How would you perform `debug_token` call using facebook php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug) the endpoint looks like

```
GET /debug_token?
     input_token={input-token}&
     access_token={access-token}
```

where

> `input_token:` the access token you want to get information about
>   `access_token`: your app access token or a valid user access token from a developer of the app

Assuming I don't have a "valid user access token from a developer of the app" - just because I don't want to refresh it every 2 months and keep always it in mind - how would I perform it using "app access token"?

The `getApplicationAccessToken()` method is protected, so there is no way to access it without overriding it to public.

Any elegant solution that I'm missing?

PS: a call example that would fail with "You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app" error due to lack of access token:

```
$tokenDebug = $fb->api('debug_token', array(
    'input_token' => $token,
));
```

PPS: the "interesting" thing is that the error from above would appear not for every `$token` but for some, and I cannot see any obvious distinction between tokens that fail and that succeed.

PPPS: `$token` is a *user access token*

PPPPS: Created a feature request for FB PHP SDK https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/637897982899835

PPPPPS: Probably it could be better to create a pull request instead, but it's 1:30am and I'm too tired for that

Comment: Why would you want to debug your _application_ access token in the first place …?

Comment: @CBroe: I want to debug user access token `$token`

Comment: The combination `app_id|app_secret` (both values concatenated with a pipe symbol in the middle) always works as app access token).

Comment: @CBroe: I know that :-) That's what `getApplicationAccessToken()` actually does, but it's protected. What I would like to avoid - is a hardcoded `app_id|app_secret` in the client code. And that's why I asked about some *elegant* solution :-)

Comment: And `getApplicationAccessToken` generates its token the same way, and is `public` in the current SDK version, see https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L734 – no idea what makes you think it was protected …?

Comment: @CBroe: It's protected in the latest stable version (the one I use) https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/v3.2.2/src/base_facebook.php#L735 I didn't look at the `master` to check, so I think it's a good answer, could you please put it as an answer and my issue will be solved with the *next stable release*

Comment: PS: probably it could be a good idea to request FB team to always append `access_token => $this->getApplicationAccessToken()` if the API endpoint is `debug_token` so that consumers didn't care of it

Comment: Well, while we’re at it, why not ask them to create a new method `debugAccessToken($token)`? :-)

Comment: @CBroe: In my solution I have just overriden `getApplicationAccessToken()` since I already extend the `Facebook` class. But I didn't like such a hack. Btw, creating a feature request, will add link to it to the question in a moment

Comment: @CBroe: done, with credits to you :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, so if one needs an app access token, `app_id|app_secret` (both values concatenated with a pipe symbol in the middle) always works.

The method `getApplicationAccessToken` seems to have been protected in the PHP SDK up to 3.2.2 – whereas `getAppId` and `getAppSecret` are already public in that version; so those could be the alternative to hard-coding id and secret in place.

Comment: Not quite always. When application is Desktop/Native, it does not work. input_token and access_token are the same in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much! Not sure why I couldn't find this anywhere. I felt like a crazy person searching for an "app access token".

Answer (score 6):

The PHP SDK has the `getOAuth2Client()` client method, that returns a `\Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client` instance.

This has the `debugToken($accessToken)` method, that returns a `\Facebook\Authentication\AccessTokenMetadata` instance that contains data about the access token.

```
$appid = '123456789';
$appsecret = 'foobar';

$api = new Facebook(['app_id' => $appid, 'app_secret' => $appsecret]);

$oauth = $api->getOAuth2Client();
$meta = $oauth->debugToken($accessToken);
$meta->validateAppId($appid); // Will throw a FacebookSDKException if invalid

$meta->getIsValid(); // boolean
$meta->getExpiresAt(); // \DateTime|null
```